# How to get degree of a node while filtering using MATCH in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with 4 levels. While filtering using `MATCH`, how can i get the "degree" of a node? I am always getting a "degree" of 1.

Here is my query:

```
MATCH (k)-[r*]->(n:ABC)
WITH k,r,n,count(k) as degree
WHERE k.Value='30 ' AND degree > 1
RETURN n,r,k,degree;
```

Comment: Please share your query

Comment: The query is :                                                                                 MATCH (k)-[r*]->(n:ABC)
WITH k,r,n,count(k) as degree
WHERE k.Value='30 ' AND degree > 1
return n,r,k,degree

Comment: I have added the query to your question. Can you explain what exactly you mean by "degree"?

Comment: It is easy to explain why you currently always get 1, but to figure out how to get the "degree" value you want, we need to know what that term means to you. Is it (a) the number of distinct k nodes, (b) the number of relationships that each distinct k node has, (c) the number of paths that each distinct k node shares with each distinct n node, or something else?

Comment: By the term degree I meant that k distinct nodes which connect to n-node and satisfies the where condition.

Answer (score 12):

You are getting count of 1 because you aggregated over all 3, start-node, end-node, and *all* relationships in the path.

This is the most efficient way.

```
MATCH (k)
WITH k, size((k)-[:TYPE]->()) as degree
WHERE k.Value='30 ' AND degree > 1
MATCH (k)-[r:TYPE]->(n:ABC)
RETURN n,r,k,degree;
```

Comment: Micheal could you point to the Size() function in the Neo4j docs ?

Comment: Docs here: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#functions-size

Comment: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-size

Comment: **1**. Yes this is much more efficient. Since number of edges are stored within the node. If one node is connected to 1000 nodes, by doing this you don't need to actually access the other 1000 nodes.
**2**. But this is slightly different from what the OP want. This is the number of distinctive **EDGES** from a node, the OP want the number of distinctive **NODES** connected from a node.

Comment: @MoonKnight Hmm, I think in graph theory, the degree (or valency) of a vertex of a graph is the number of edges incident to the vertex, with loops counted twice - and OP is asking for *degree*, not the number of *NODES*.

Comment: @danodonovan you are right. I was only looking at the OP's original code rather than reading his title.

Comment: I have apretty large graph 4m nodes and 40m edges - this `WITH .., size.. as degree` line maxes my CPUs and ultimately crashes neo4j

Comment: I want to get count number of edges by a property of edge. For example: get number of edges for each node in which "edge.x > 10" x is a property of edge

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j `size` function is now deprecated, and `apoc.node.degree` is recommended instead;

```
MATCH (k)-[r*]->(n:ABC)
WITH k,r,n, apoc.node.degree(k) as degree
WHERE k.Value='30 ' AND degree > 1
RETURN n,r,k,degree;
```

NB You will need [APOC to be installed](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/installation/) on your local Neo4j instance

Answer (score 1):

More information would be helpful, but in general you can get the degree of a node by doing something like:

```
MATCH (n)--(other)
WHERE n.id = {id}
RETURN count(other)
```

If you want to find degrees for many nodes you can leave out the `WHERE` or specify a more generic query:

```
MATCH (n)--(other)
WHERE n.property = {value}
RETURN n, count(other)
```

Comment: Using `id()` is certainly the way to get the Neo4j internal ID, but since those IDs can be recycled I generally use a property (in this case `id`) as an example