# Neo4j Cypher: filter results by in-degree

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am running the following Neo4j Cypher query:

```
MATCH (n:ARTICLE { article_id: '1234' })-[k:CONNECTS]->(r:ARTICLE) 
RETURN n,k,r;
```

Now I'd like to filter for all those `r` nodes that within the matched results have in-degree (ie. degree of `(n)-[k]->(r)`) greater than 1. How would I do that?

(I thought this questions is distinct from [How to get degree of a node while filtering using MATCH in neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32775427/1529646) , which is why I decided to ask it here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the size of the number of inbound relationships between the nodes in a `WHERE` clause.

```
MATCH (n:ARTICLE { article_id: '1234' })-[k:CONNECTS]->(r:ARTICLE)
WHERE size((n)-[:CONNECTS]->(r)) > 1
RETURN n,k,r
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Was somehow stuck trying to use a "WITH" clause.